# Monitor setup for basic Simpy simulation

Tags: python, monitor, simpy

Excuse my code, I'm new and it's not very pythonic. I'm struggling to set up a basic simulation with monitor. Preferably using Simpy's Monitor class.

I've defined probability distributions for orders of three pizzas, each with various ingredients. I want to simulate 1000 days of orders to produce probability distributions for daily requirements of each ingredient. My code generates a mean, but I also need variance and for cleanliness would rather just monitor the output.

I'm sure it's simple by can't get the Monitor() and .observ() code to work. Any help? Cheers!!

P.s. Pizza toppings below do not necessarily reflect author's preference.

```
import numpy as np
import random, sys
from SimPy.Simulation import *

class g:
   crust = 0
   cheese = 0
   pepperoni = 0
   pineapple = 0
   olive = 0

def pepperoni_pizza():
   mean = 10 #average pepperoni pizzas ordered
   std = 2 #standard deviation of pizzas ordered
   norders = np.random.normal(mean, std) #draw random value
   g.crust += norders * 10 #value indicates the amount of ingredient required for this pizza
   g.cheese += norders * 5
   g.pepperoni += norders * 5
   g.pineapple += norders * 0
   g.olive += norders * 5

def pineapple_pizza():
   mean = 20
   std = 6
   norders = np.random.normal(mean, std)
   g.crust += norders * 10
   g.cheese += norders * 0
   g.pepperoni += norders * 0
   g.pineapple += norders * 5
   g.olive += norders * 5

def cheese_pizza():
   mean = 7
   std = 3
   norders = np.random.normal(mean, std)
   g.crust += norders * 10
   g.cheese += norders * 10
   g.pepperoni += norders * 0
   g.pineapple += norders * 0
   g.olive += norders * 5


def main():
   nreps = 1000
   for rep in range(nreps):
      while True:
         pepperoni_pizza()
         pineapple_pizza()
         cheese_pizza()
         break
   print 'crust needed =', g.crust/float(nreps)
   print 'cheese needed =', g.cheese/float(nreps)
   print 'pepperoni needed =', g.pepperoni/float(nreps)
   print 'pineapple needed =', g.pineapple/float(nreps)
   print 'olive needed =', g.olive/float(nreps)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Good thing you don't want pineapple on your pizza...

Comment: Not sure why you need to use simpy for this type of simulation, you can just use numpy arrays, since there is no event dependence.